# Brute force a password with a lot of hash (of the same password)

Tags: brute-force, md5

I have a list of approximatively 1000 entities, defined using the following code :

```
list[i] = md5_salt_unix_hash(random_salt, password)
```

Where the `random_salt` is generated in each iteration and the `password` is already the same.

I want to know if there is any mmethod to brute force the password by exploiting this list or if this list is useless and that I just need 1 hash to brute force the password.

Comment: it means you call this function (md5_salt_unix_hash(random_salt, password)) for each password?

Comment: I have just one password (for example "toto") and i have a list like this :
(`$1$saltone$md5(toto+saltone)`, `$1$salttwo$md5(toto+salttwo)`, 
`$1$saltthree$md5(toto+salthree)`).


Like you can see, the password is always the same (`toto`) but the salt change (`saltone`, `salttwo`, `saltthree`)

Answer (score 1):

The latter - you *just* need to hash each word in your password guess list with one of the salts and then compare each resulting hash.

Note that the salt is not considered private - all that a long list of different salts against the password gives you is a small number possible representations of that password in a DB. It does not make it easier to guess the password.